# how to write superscripts(like squares,powers) in struts 1.3 properties file?

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-config, struts-validation

i have a requirement to print units like m(square) in front end. So, for this i have to mention in properties file. But properties file is not accepting to write like that.
Please help me.

Comment: Please show what you've done, as well as the error you are getting.

Comment: thanks for your response. No error is coming but intended output is not coming like m2.how to write powers in properties file

Comment: Ok, can you show how the property is declared, and how it is output?

Comment: In my jspfile:<bean:message key="dsprocess.unit"/>In my Application Resources.properties file:dsprocess.unit=Volume(cm2).In properties file i am not able to  write units(cm2) superscript or power.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `sup` html-tag in your properties file:

```
dsprocess.unit=Volume(cm<sup>2</sup>)
```